# Refining generic type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-closure-compiler

In google closure compiler, you can refine a generic by doing typeof or instanceof.
For example, here I take a generic and treat it like an object:

```
/**
 * @param {T} obj
 * @return {T}
 * @template T
 */
function cloneIfObject(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    return objectClone(obj);
  }
  return obj;
}

/**
 * Stub function that only accepts object type
 *
 * @param {!Object} obj
 * @return {!Object}
 */
function objectClone(obj) {
  return obj; //Pretend to clone
}
```

I tried implementing this in typescript, but I'm unable to treat it like an object.

```
function cloneIfObject<T>(obj: T) {
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        return { ...obj }; //Error: Spread types may only be created from object types.
    }

    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        return { ...obj }; //Error: Spread types may only be created from object types.
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add cast? like `{... <object>obj}`. And is not that the same effect as `Object.assign` ?

Comment: @A.Akram The cast still fails `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

You are right that `Object.assign` is the same as spread. I think `Object.assign({}, <object>obj)` works, but I'm curious as to why spread isn't working.

Comment: A generic function which does not use the generic type argument, great

Comment: @Dummy Can you clarify? I'm new to typescript

Comment: You might want to read this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot---

Comment: @Dummy I'm not sure that applies to my case. My module doesn't know anything about type T. It should allow primitives, functions, classes, objects, etc. as inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `typeof` for what you are trying to do:

> These typeof type guards are recognized in two different forms: typeof
>   v === "typename" and typeof v !== "typename", where "typename" must be
>   "number", "string", "boolean", or "symbol". While TypeScript won’t
>   stop you from comparing to other strings, the language won’t recognize
>   those expressions as type guards.

The second one will be a valid use, as soon as they fix [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727) (there is already a [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13288)).